Google Play Console: unable to submit new version because other tracks contain version with policy violation
My app, which is currently in Open Testing on Google Play, used to need the Android USE_EXACT_ALARM permission.
I've completed a new version, which, instead, uses only SCHEDULE_EXACT ALARM and I've tried to submit it on the Play Console – the process went fine on the Internal Testing track.
However, when I attempted to promote the version to Closed Testing, I got an error that there was a version in Open Testing that used a sensitive permission.
Consequently, I left the Closed Testing release in draft and tried to promote the new version to Open Testing. This time the Console said I could not continue with that release, because a version in Closed Testing used sensitive permissions.
So, I am left with a Catch-22 situation, in which I cannot submit a new non-policy-violating version because the previous versions violate a policy.
Does anyone have any ideas what I could do (other than contact Google, which I've already done, or delete the app and start from scratch)?
Thank you!

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/115145
